# how to close auto generate -webkit -moz and so on in vscode

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

when I want to type transform in vscode,It will automatic generate `-webkit-transform: translate(-50%  50%); -moz-transform: translate(-50%  50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%  50%); -o-transform: translate(-50%  50%);`,I want to close this feature.

```
@keyframes moveInLeft {
    0% {
        border-radius: ;
        transform: translate(-50%  50%);
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%  50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%  50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%  50%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%  50%);
}
}
```

The same thing happen when I type border-radius

```
    border-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    -ms-border-radius: 1px;
    -o-border-radius: 1px;
```

Comment: may I ask why? you will gain ~2% browser support by using these prefixes

Comment: you can look this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72065282/sass-format-is-broken-when-i-type-border-radius-in-vscode

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these few steps to turn it off

1. Go to file and choose preferences.
2. Click on settings and from the search bar type css
3. Look for auto prefixed from the dropped down list.
4. Toggle is off.