# sass format is broken when I type border-radius in vscode

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I want to add border-radius to a element in my scss file.
before:

```
.card {

    &__side {
        height:50rem;

        &--front {
            background-color: orange;
        }
    }
}
```

after:

```
.card {
    border-radius: ;
        &__side :;
    -webkit-border-radius:;
    -moz-border-radius:;
    -ms-border-radius:;
    -o-border-radius:;
{
        height:50rem;

        &--front {
            background-color: orange;
        }
    }
}
```

the format is corrupted.I want to fix this in vscode.anyone can help me?thanks!!!!!
the same thing happen when the vscode auto-generate `-webkit-border-*:; -moz-border-*:; -ms-border-*:; -o-border-*:;`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with certain CSS auto-prefix plugins right now. You can disable it for the time being or look for a different one.